Bend Theory Application (Solving for Two Unknowns with Many Known Variables)
I have a very specific problem I'm trying to solve that I thought would be simple algebra and may not be after all.  My application is solving for a couple of unknown parameters in a bend theory application (an engineering concept used to predict the before and after geometry of a bent piece of sheet metal).
I've searched for an answer to this but there doesn't seem to be any equations available online.  Note: there are a ton of resources for calculating bend theory parameters, but they never have the set of knowns and unknowns that I have here.  Searching for this information is made harder by the fact that bending is filled with a bunch of "rules of thumb" and lookup tables rather than hard math.
Here is the setup of the problem:

T - Thickness of material
Ti - Position of the neutral line
R - Inner bend radius
L - Blank (unbent) length
P - Bend position
F - Flange height
S - Base length
Additionally:  K = Ti / T  (K is a much more useful number than Ti and is industry standard)
The above image shows a cross section of a bent piece of flat sheet metal.  The bend is 90 degrees (there is a more generic case at different angles, but I don't need that for my application).
The part starts out with a perfectly rectangular cross section with thickness T and length L.  The part is bent with the center of the bend distance P from the end of the part.  The part bends into a 90deg shape with an arc-shaped bend region in the middle.  The ends of the blank stay square.  Material on the outside of the part stretches around the bend and material on the inside compresses.  There is a transition boundary between stretching and compressing called the "neutral line" (the green line in the above image).  The path length of the green line NEVER changes before, after, or during bending.
The center of the arc-shaped bend area is located distance P from the end of the part measured along the neutral line (including the 45deg arc section in the middle of the bend).
In my application, I know T, L, S, F, and P.  I don't know R or K (and thus Ti).
Here are my two questions:

Is the problem/geometry properly constrained?  I believe it is but that more of a hunch.  I encountered some weird situations while trying to solve this where I would get an input variable cancelling out of the equation implying there is a still a degree of freedom somewhere.  I don't know how to rigorously analyze the degrees of freedom of a problem like this.

What are the equations for K and R?



If I understand your picture correctly (P is measured along the neutral line, right?) the equations are as simple as $L=\frac \pi 2R+[S-(R+T)]+[F-(R+T)]$ (quarter-circle plus two straight segments) and $P=[F-(R+T)]+(R+T_i)\frac \pi 4$ (the straight segment plus one eighth of the full circle of radius $R+T_i$). In the first one only $R$ is unknown, so you can find it, and then $T_i$ can be found from the second one. As you said, $K$ is merely $T_i/T$.

@fedja I think ${\pi\over2}R$ in your first equation should be substituted by ${\pi\over2}(R+T_i)$.

@Intelligentipauca You are right: I misinterpreted $L$ on the picture as the measurement along the inner side of the bent sheet, so with the correct interpretation, you get a 2 by 2 system, which, unfortunately, is degenerate then and allows you to find only the quantity $\frac\pi 2(R+T_i)-2R$, but not $R$ and $T_i$ individually, so in this case the problem is unsolvable as posed :-(

It sounds like the answer to #1 is "no".  Can someone show how to come to that conclusion with the proper steps and put it in an answer (so I can accept it).
Also, can whoever is voting down this question reconsider?  My question is legitimate, properly researched before asking, and follows the guidelines of the forum.
